# RX_ERR in ifconfig ouput

Tags: networking

How can we debug the RX_ERR and find the point of the failure.

I can see that number of RX_ERR and RX_DROP are the same . There isn't any TX_ERR and TX_DROP.

Even when verified from the switch end I can't find any error.

How can we verify the packets which are having RX_ERR. and is it common that EX_ERR and RX_DROP count will be the same .

Comment: Are the duplex settings the same at both ends of the cable (ie, on the host and on the switch)?

Comment: Yups the duplex setting are same. Can you guide me How can I find out which packets were exactly failing. and is CRC mismatch the only reason for RX_ERR